# Ошибка типа Access Violation при определенном тесте ( язык С)

Tags: c, графы

Доброго всем времени суток. Столкнулся с проблемой, которая не дает уснуть мне уже несколько дней.

Задача крайне простая. Нам дается граф, заданный списком ребер. В результате мы должны ответить на вопрос: "Можно ли в нем построить Эйлеров цикл?" Однако на одном из тестов, она рушиться, выводя одноименную ошибку с названием темы.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

static bool visited[1001];
static short a[1001][1001];

void dfs (long long int v, long long int z) {
    visited[v] = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<=z; ++i) {
        if (a[v][i] != 0 && visited[i] == 0){
                dfs(i,z);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    long long int x,m;
    scanf("%lld %lld", &x, &m); // кол-во вершин и кол-во ребер
    int b,d;
    for (int i = 1; i<=x; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j<=x; j++){
            a[i][j]=0;
        }
    }
    for(int i = 0; i<m; i++){  // представляю граф матрицей
        scanf("%i %i", &b, &d);
        a[b][d] = 1;
        a[d][b] = 1;
    }
    for (int i=1; i<=x; i++){
        visited[i] = 0;
    }
    if (visited[1] == 0) { // ДФС на проверку того, что граф состоит из 1 компонента связности
        dfs(1,m);
    }
    bool fl = 0;
    for (int i=1; i<=x; i++){ // Проверка провеки ДФС-а
        if (visited[i] == 0){
            fl = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 1; i<=x; i++){
        for (int j = 1; j<=x; j++){
            if (a[i][j] == 1){
                sum++;
            }
        }
        if (sum%2 != 0){
            fl = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (fl == 0){
        printf("YES");
    }
    else{
        printf("NO");
    }
}
```

Сам тест такой:

```
1000 2000
42 468
335 501
170 725
479 359
963 465
706 146
282 828
962 492
996 943
828 437
392 605
903 154
293 383
422 717
719 896
448 727
772 539
870 913
668 300
36 895
704 812
323 334
674 665
142 712
254 869
548 645
663 758
38 860
724 742
530 779
317 36
191 843
289 107
41 943
265 649
447 806
891 730
371 351
7 102
394 549
630 624
85 955
757 841
967 377
932 309
945 440
627 324
538 539
119 83
930 542
834 116
640 659
705 931
978 307
674 387
22 746
925 73
271 830
778 574
98 513
987 291
162 637
356 768
656 575
32 53
351 151
942 725
967 431
108 192
8 338
458 288
754 384
946 910
210 759
222 589
423 947
507 31
414 169
901 592
763 656
411 360
625 538
549 484
596 42
603 351
292 837
375 21
597 22
349 200
669 485
282 735
54 1000
419 939
901 789
128 468
729 894
649 484
808 422
311 618
814 515
310 617
936 452
601 250
520 557
799 304
225 9
845 610
990 703
196 486
94 344
524 588
315 504
449 201
459 619
581 797
799 282
590 799
10 158
473 623
539 293
39 180
191 658
959 192
816 889
157 512
203 635
273 56
329 647
363 887
876 434
870 143
845 417
882 999
323 652
22 700
558 477
893 390
76 713
601 511
4 870
862 689
402 790
256 424
3 586
183 286
89 427
618 758
833 933
170 155
722 190
977 330
369 693
426 556
435 550
442 513
146 61
719 754
140 424
280 997
688 530
550 438
867 950
194 196
298 417
287 106
489 283
456 735
115 702
317 672
787 264
314 356
186 54
913 809
833 946
314 757
322 559
647 983
482 145
197 223
130 162
536 451
174 467
45 660
293 440
254 25
155 511
746 650
187 314
475 23
169 19
788 906
959 392
203 626
478 415
315 825
335 875
373 160
834 71
488 298
519 178
774 271
764 669
193 986
103 481
214 628
803 100
528 626
544 925
24 973
62 182
4 433
506 594
726 32
493 143
223 287
65 901
188 361
414 975
271 171
236 834
712 761
897 668
286 551
141 695
696 625
20 126
577 695
659 303
372 467
679 594
852 485
19 465
120 153
801 88
61 927
11 758
171 316
577 228
44 759
165 110
883 87
566 488
578 475
626 628
630 929
424 521
903 963
124 597
738 262
196 526
265 261
203 117
31 327
12 772
412 548
154 521
791 925
189 764
941 852
663 830
901 714
959 579
366 8
478 201
59 440
304 761
358 325
478 109
114 888
802 851
461 429
994 385
406 541
112 705
836 357
73 351
824 486
557 217
627 358
527 358
338 272
870 362
897 23
618 113
718 697
586 42
424 130
230 566
560 933
297 856
54 963
585 735
655 973
458 370
533 964
608 484
912 636
68 849
676 939
224 143
755 512
742 176
460 826
222 871
627 935
206 784
851 399
280 702
194 735
638 535
557 994
177 706
963 549
882 301
414 642
143 856
463 612
878 425
679 753
444 297
674 41
314 876
73 819
611 18
933 113
696 170
832 41
489 686
91 498
590 991
146 354
315 652
741 45
259 336
760 193
606 265
182 504
830 776
609 293
998 550
557 562
628 468
542 130
241 814
175 602
78 216
684 214
993 825
602 393
760 671
429 28
85 76
787 499
971 288
848 605
504 222
664 707
364 11
172 490
241 165
543 620
914 592
705 819
233 751
206 976
540 304
423 99
248 585
649 972
865 914
76 546
713 547
679 770
263 520
986 290
945 866
541 246
509 319
871 602
324 133
473 153
88 571
764 902
104 424
528 601
970 16
566 29
544 348
89 944
638 410
464 50
682 589
343 609
61 222
759 955
889 147
691 950
844 431
621 749
68 537
784 36
227 186
39 854
630 225
749 924
360 258
767 945
956 319
727 412
26 356
2 550
497 585
516 965
343 76
914 143
197 949
73 427
607 174
430 405
706 627
813 376
94 566
37 737
142 815
995 257
653 937
839 483
356 16
132 231
842 626
12 638
187 691
651 663
635 894
354 417
453 9
263 234
455 304
635 304
257 149
125 318
214 110
29 201
81 319
859 51
156 362
265 904
677 644
910 903
562 490
949 283
654 675
221 403
924 832
370 879
260 9
620 972
4 946
782 505
393 686
314 699
590 723
939 38
411 462
235 509
962 960
494
516
270 938
870 59
701 972
265 118
216 556
816 331
40 213
289 83
955 86
711 485
775 381
816 952
542 116
680 111
899 74
789 978
133 957
690 114
9 942
791 724
364 29
185 779
201 72
886 975
72 334
868 154
296 169
826 677
630 651
599 310
694 687
81 117
250 668
529 680
865 422
406 827
817 517
727 667
88 682
965 341
687 22
663 722
65 310
416 903
874 125
942 746
763 424
532 807
269 319
603 908
308 482
13 137
631 115
810 85
557 291
294 997
153 55
346 709
249 492
713 132
115 440
959 723
705 996
53 270
480 239
424 919
867 660
499 487
197 463
634 159
23 147
393 38
926 648
459 603
808 99
831 293
601 279
800 353
449 883
541 316
576 763
568 337
398 419
898 829
852 817
231 450
926 659
230 521
941 561
148 163
656 676
793 362
755 399
147 715
947 189
570 639
664 76
516 522
476 616
529 235
571 906
465 558
963 162
525 550
470 331
924 351
334 926
911 738
337 338
279 394
637 715
165 592
950 136
506 338
5 338
624 665
971 609
569 282
86 153
374 653
195 877
827 397
573 250
641 175
820 944
612 942
290 420
566 806
586 217
451 616
610 65
167 894
75 510
301 696
574 590
162 173
969 359
32 269
427 511
423 775
780 911
553 183
392 496
765 875
365 903
256 461
475 973
822 123
548 578
790 606
196 595
951 344
755 482
13 673
440 429
913 763
968 409
416 909
224 760
435 205
487 320
959 946
807 167
701 368
693 788
533 557
975 448
22 284
223 332
377 584
949 724
983 19
777 221
112 183
857 491
926 325
487 678
970 644
535 678
669 69
992 197
784 829
728 427
872 698
613 704
28 409
546 509
186 239
238 444
314 502
851 129
112 651
150 193
455 870
682 466
268 714
794 635
473 973
831 902
443 178
878 771
703 365
382 591
824 238
24 180
596 170
328 43
311 183
59 927
488 671
529 652
259 214
861 784
287 743
611 473
129 435
842 719
504 868
866 939
882 258
751 615
599 459
662 64
757 808
279 490
436 366
76 587
387 834
361 331
49 929
493 434
841 767
736 811
600 838
893 983
329 353
370 245
795 609
253 648
433 536
209 265
498 244
650 16
842 190
101 813
649 524
852 475
634 892
201 855
991 698
920 781
579 932
545 341
488 900
526 484
539 493
194 253
12 561
835 841
498 786
530 541
806 792
393 211
550 579
980 972
278 74
194 621
498 827
277 791
583 579
160 419
490 160
450 925
73 381
9 968
209 478
504 371
608 197
75 723
612 20
762 57
891 164
684 717
933 453
742 955
814 863
397 461
616 905
600 137
681 199
33 388
585 241
518 7
671 242
883 250
524 759
106 622
96 297
917 679
179 580
59 578
751 8
730 82
996 679
677 754
900 785
566 94
609 173
244 930
515 169
56 192
974 923
749 652
987 145
447 578
518 630
917 875
792 470
913 147
694 92
816 950
858 641
53 237
552 488
227 163
956 184
395 181
98 66
66 514
262 579
79 879
141 612
948 446
171 976
490 751
150 334
866 215
283 8
433 897
368 523
883 811
642 232
188 706
480 322
539 352
448 209
647 277
760 190
423 667
487 456
29 615
861 254
778 349
504 862
432 83
456 198
107 753
822 297
282 22
456 948
125 319
136 377
775 860
999 75
254 923
636 644
889 154
233 748
681 927
679 451
802 962
200 856
364 717
574 562
246 474
275 551
354 182
288 700
111 644
466 173
530 982
113 477
382 248
891 672
806 373
33 990
321 166
432 659
294 207
579 949
207 172
167 397
698 21
695 530
789 110
985 970
979 618
16 627
685 169
907 929
98 119
391 200
786 487
200 421
711 272
814 416
86 319
581 332
268 388
445 187
508 361
828 75
432 153
272 269
694 886
338 312
605 678
407 769
23 414
1 543
538 39
389 356
290 648
182 94
585 988
762 494
218 502
483 448
666 754
105 85
96 526
222 965
782 873
107 657
344 594
869 81
412 714
969 252
217 80
769 41
532 934
780 664
260 654
937 96
366 875
721 836
681 977
456 726
72 809
560 157
603 833
906 441
376 563
886 963
81 837
798 203
509 81
341 77
59 494
741 547
475 774
98 881
336 73
401 708
956 667
142 589
482 169
316 397
226 10
13 137
456 763
44 743
22 923
513 249
19 369
718 715
651 291
336 760
170 896
304 641
980 200
106 792
662 682
653 754
34 30
988 43
254 84
421 815
719 245
64 230
653 865
770 471
6 48
595 488
327 277
324 541
680 991
589 711
272 946
222 471
184 590
956 979
780 7
263 136
488 197
34 89
936 780
994 791
963 966
2 106
808 568
670 135
672 458
999 546
598 219
839 845
373 564
29 265
802 724
491 605
602 228
198 693
772 364
302 364
722 566
422 446
611 496
742 23
813 152
16 56
394 739
280 883
609 655
823 708
246 339
145 291
340 155
605 624
226 79
725 982
331 734
224 595
131 847
988 446
806 617
751 490
339 964
136 698
210 631
225 909
738 475
921 373
294 856
735 562
57 607
185 76
383 120
742 433
685 780
280 284
668 837
126 119
738 29
120 578
738 92
557 796
61 902
794 433
137 581
876 908
185 75
720 791
477 42
352 330
291 975
73 592
190 788
491 240
894 54
64 682
904 6
177 480
696 140
469 999
84 640
516 622
994 827
723 839
829 582
400 979
892 24
944 835
244 350
703 708
503 142
688 347
892 638
414 401
817 691
163 936
127 411
878 383
261 190
706 875
664 723
196 567
361 39
589 812
246 468
426 868
190 543
64 548
503 618
100 24
227 204
49 52
571 637
459 968
457 406
532 963
820 976
557 532
496 45
592 804
389 916
451 320
273 792
384 134
776 643
570 301
955 79
586 258
334 894
491 104
751 234
723 272
612 991
339 642
259 48
353 659
480 303
684 991
3 569
423 896
136 9
362 743
195 700
189 179
43 358
942 848
470 346
381 914
965 711
62 386
74 505
463 704
103 70
155 530
553 75
150 731
245 845
50 119
66 364
553 774
471 732
748 512
870 399
499 104
353 680
54 44
523 89
564 835
851 23
241 912
493 652
581 478
617 877
179 221
616 349
799 180
636 858
884 663
903 263
421 771
23 274
842 687
889 918
718 893
699 268
750 66
390 933
620 82
4 131
29 632
590 153
631 173
865 408
296 429
682 491
611 178
72 237
460 644
841 634
38 894
631 275
994 783
204 462
291 663
308 998
152 424
891 718
641 704
567 884
662 660
246 387
652 766
602 841
210 498
284 251
59 422
176 582
788 272
288 1000
505 980
139 701
531 462
119 206
541 829
460 623
399 761
99 936
482 615
568 494
597 162
747 539
671 539
477 556
918 372
761 753
759 434
256 66
727 402
35 760
394 549
274 793
194 934
138 104
691 212
695 669
628 499
990 249
880 648
150 932
670 876
599 450
437 600
124 444
732 155
862 435
386 968
817 394
705 867
954 309
224 685
793 668
49 470
931 812
815 91
428 744
605 600
475 196
507 159
590 859
810 890
448 41
819 365
976 27
90 504
67 413
841 571
677 396
642 987
652 110
188 84
86 391
251 687
756 382
129 503
278 863
425 566
873 833
886 429
647 890
479 884
926 266
261 46
779 822
856 521
928 774
135 252
676 337
335 2
738 311
975 591
357 72
81 936
146 283
826 719
574 713
38 999
906 163
718 693
540 48
947 104
232 116
840 859
830 646
395 200
646 273
676 863
73 774
481 239
898 543
609 204
278 126
135 402
79 383
170 737
479 940
139 722
427 664
678 576
725 982
701 962
863 3
449 96
685 17
138 508
994 285
945 260
822 59
644 669
678 120
858 42
892 265
624 916
73 930
842 716
616 537
958 760
701 453
94 242
830 449
228 799
225 325
275 134
886 39
171 863
630 85
910 879
924 86
401 25
194 106
413 766
768 408
678 785
705 791
835 892
622 86
735 191
543 999
87 19
622 425
598 377
255 670
109 928
494 69
367 103
439 601
820 319
291 985
340 557
809 633
479 815
788 240
75 21
828 555
989 442
799 643
3 322
105 947
57 510
834 709
762 534
687 805
386 143
843 261
162 621
344 579
188 114
64 592
935 416
657 762
13 412
960 252
739 371
125 508
8 585
952 102
490 959
442 791
14 413
856 61
94 473
403 677
544 374
267 652
276 529
533 762
470 504
730 108
893 452
954 393
571 520
473 408
495 506
441 384
263 410
608 39
361 472
172 655
948 515
524 230
490 767
888 757
633 471
740 667
523 284
161 554
706 92
260 387
688 630
43 318
46 357
389 453
155 467
834 761
920 632
739 268
777 99
315 321
54 8
470 217
723 843
8 464
261 948
794 631
718 44
377 315
627 118
335 621
172 793
965 155
867 694
665 776
1 213
101 552
477 380
944 878
790 362
386 273
435 145
562 564
505 947
889 309
158 431
124 465
75 347
838 982
319 612
293 592
833 124
462 992
462 331
499 370
292 401
180 118
318 915
596 442
937 868
29 454
910 974
982 504
570 817
884 368
386 403
231 158
682 568
311 867
688 172
478 246
765 239
672 48
116 593
312 658
406 54
172 581
741 531
676 321
791 378
999 587
605 490
632 745
389 611
719 920
260 928
610 120
480 717
301 397
854 459
831 594
807 850
855 273
161 295
55 334
147 230
472 429
560 242
422 689
367 34
686 271
330 262
861 209
983 163
507 879
980 898
888 539
470 784
541 796
267 634
510 558
318 135
54 136
259 594
844 694
467 952
141 95
938 175
513 98
552 696
818 493
293 238
531 614
297 711
390 629
810 787
745 841
183 570
121 394
293 963
215 528
808 195
706 714
12 914
694 665
204 996
763 382
947 910
49 769
625 512
955 236
128 634
241 863
128 578
818 341
143 101
401 559
477 155
936 431
832 296
538 624
923 928
30 212
212 755
881 254
294 322
786 529
444 1
556 672
271 453
376 632
641 935
41 987
835 249
540 766
797 313
263 53
732 988
465 558
249 557
171 451
183 302
294 100
333 45
332 76
5 51
27 67
739 802
624 844
442 381
696 919
660 364
629 330
89 855
614 980
570 667
680 578
838 403
116 293
724 873
449 324
154 949
396 198
509 909
412 994
666 782
203 611
829 257
706 966
24 770
716 254
806 685
479 146
841 834
286 901
969 995
634 886
349 282
33 257
911 873
983 902
307 636
861 472
528 138
344 769
234 996
172 604
943 12
880 35
513 594
531 162
235 259
927 907
192 444
189 228
720 485
225 94
436 225
95 583
868 628
6 147
687 590
541 238
851 760
579 957
678 404
43 301
812 226
144 596
17 616
805 7
369 642
336 699
326 314
24 313
619 458
397 340
87 95
847 44
523 912
281 456
359 848
871 991
874 328
414 455
897 473
451 242
642 647
526 214
825 930
696 404
595 994
68 188
641 80
42 126
535 861
1 908
622 693
294 118
718 404
944 894
640 12
926 29
979 749
851 893
445 655
624 354
37 548
347 827
62 905
239 572
887 406
300 57
729 268
752 20
992 167
718 847
94 188
422 913
868 300
445 898
202 329
943 105
642 769
297 263
721 245
919 626
220 585
175 985
460 150
15 696
504 33
852 538
815 364
652 220
291 918
684 919
585 253
587 270
249 138
398 425
169 28
149 994
383 272
670 894
878 15
105 485
944 496
812 294
893 799
991 300
891 494
75 550
775 315
174 70
219 866
834 239
912 253
464 509
150 89
246 232
921 107
272 369
422 259
158 648
983 239
123 724
907 707
190 157
346 352
924 119
551 98
837 592
407 511
814 652
881 845
744 742
246 579
950 706
515 786
228 625
205 357
918 228
556 103
287 469
699 980
412 490
759 491
776 411
133 90
297 951
113 123
530 673
837 278
554 977
671 86
653 752
398 752
2 436
694 73
917 717
329 512
126 839
297 940
545 57
827 903
759 589
22 587
109 778
629 980
948 550
281 246
129 63
427 720
678 92
48 786
232 407
685 955
770 710
957 422
946 466
17 861
498 336
191 678
50 6
887 389
676 144
378 131
488 556
483 254
1 755
290 489
216 9
311 941
800 998
708 455
305 238
486 500
793 614
613 683
984 352
130 138
34 601
865 684
858 969
711 969
709 642
733 438
685 500
702 870
584 257
693 641
88 13
811 821
836 664
616 898
678 775
135 554
534 879
287 625
735 76
350 713
985 625
793 505
823 56
914 463
474 85
161 123
54 398
823 751
338 918
7 932
198 506
237 358
600 291
899 986
448 85
593 726
997 856
829 339
343 429
796 743
38 507
768 54
794 506
147 610
925 855
466 240
207 210
493 500
176 37
62 648
619 14
728 713
897 910
842 131
91 35
916 287
524 667
345 737
38 417
894 950
972 845
778 286
201 591
286 326
119 669
7 730
9 542
226 537
981 717
471 385
748 329
937 205
701 524
365 412
41 251
505 484
767 142
671 846
507 89
257 108
267 858
679 200
675 156
192 991
833 859
997 918
291 968
708 235
247 463
403 240
427 96
907 315
351 587
280 777
823 880
302 813
677 165
358 571
39 313
145 562
181 201
644 857
62 648
940 809
291 453
980 619
420 8
285 548
978 676
614 710
372 643
340 337
622 502
35 130
359 437
470 898
505 799
203 106
239 33
66 517
482 580
24 728
772 314
383 141
817 489
320 590
514 260
852 272
284 365
39 13
185 760
502 575
734 60
715 650
596 523
542 417
378 53
566 892
139 311
968 56
788 225
223 440
442 649
805 835
369 442
873 669
975 177
138 634
242 746
19 16
975 253
847 957
525 967
582 145
241 335
297 877
28 206
19 292
642 466
192 472
260 701
218 17
944 625
65 506
158 503
667 276
47 633
790 47
146 4
153 902
327 154
185 650
351 406
347 26
971 337
796 794
324 533
857 897
211 777
693 551
291 796
853 351
316 37
362 761
985 730
535 51
83 807
937 585
791 618
183 67
117 389
```

Есть подозрение, что проблема с ДФС-ом, но где именно, я точно сказать не могу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Есть подозрение, что проблема с ДФС-ом

Есть подозрение, что проблема с индексами массивов. "Access violation" - в 99% случаев это ошибка индексации. В самом деле, смотрим код. Вот у вас стоит вызов функции:

```
if (visited[1] == 0) {
        dfs(1,m);
}
```

Чему равняется значение *m*? А вот:

```
scanf("%lld %lld", &x, &m); // кол-во вершин и кол-во ребер
1000 2000
```

Т.е. m == 2000. А как это значение используется внутри функции? А вот:

```
for (int i=1; i<=z; ++i) { // Здесь z == m
    if (a[v][i] != 0 && visited[i] == 0){
            dfs(i,z);
    }
}
```

Т.е. у Вас написано: a[1][2000]. Вот и выход за границы индекса...

А вообще, настоятельно рекомендую:

1. Сделать ввод этих гигантских массивов не с клавиатуры, а из файла. Тогде не нужно будет повторно выбивать эти сумасшедшие числа.
2. Откомпилировать программу с ключом отладки (gcc -g)
3. Запустить её под отладчиком gdb/ Он Вам сразу покажет место ошибки.

Comment: Боже... Спасибо огромное! На столько тупая ошибка, что я даже не подозревал!

Comment: @Андрей - "На столько тупая ошибка"   - Тяжелее всего найти самую глупую ошибку. Просто даже в голову не приходит. Это я по собственному опыту :-)